# How to make QtDesigner offer Enumeration for Plugin Property

Tags: qt

I'm trying to deploy my Qt Ui Widget as a Qt Designer Plugin in accordance to the Guide at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html

However, I just can't seem to figure out how to make QtDesigner present the User with a Dropdown in the Property-Editor for Enumeration Properties.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

1) put the enum right after the "public:" of your class and immediately thereafter use the Q_ENUM macro

```
    class myEnumContainingClass {
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_PROPERTY(FOO my_property READ getMyEnumProperty WRITE setMyEnumProperty DESIGNABLE true)
    public:
      enum FOO {
        BAR
      };
      Q_ENUM(FOO)
      explicit MyEnumContainingClass();
      ...
```

2) use only the key of the enum, not the whole enum::string in the domXml()-section of the plugin like this

```
    <property name="theEnumHoldingProperty">
      <enum>BAR</enum>
    </property>
```

Although I would have still preferred to have the whole enum::string appear in the Dropdown within Qt Designer for consistency, at least it works this way.